# How to align `OverflowBar` children in Cross Axis?

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there any way to align `OverflowBar` children in Cross Axis? There is a overflowAlignment parameter, but it works only in vertical layout to align children horizontally. And I need to align vertically when `OverflowBar` is in horizontal layout.

What I have:
[image]

What I want to achieve:
[image]

I achieve that using `Wrap` widget, but it is not what I need, cause it wraps differently.

Comment: Can you please provide more details on what you tried? Did you try setting the overflowAlignment to OverflowBarAlignment.start? Also, if you tried the wrap, what alignment did you use? Instead of wrap, did you try row? if yes what alignments? did you try listview? Please provide more information.

Comment: Concerning `overflowAlignment`: "/// This parameter is only used if the horizontal layout overflows, i.e. /// if there isn't enough horizontal room for the [children] and [spacing]. /// In that case the overflow bar will expand to fill the available /// width and it will layout its [children] in a column. The /// horizontal alignment of each child within that column is /// defined by this parameter".

Comment: As you see, `overflowAlignment` works only in vertical layout. So, yes, I have tried it, but it cannot help. `Row` and `ListView` are not suitable for me, these widgets don't change layout dynamically. But, yes, everything is OK with alignment within these widgets.